# How to center a image but don't let it block the nav bar menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have entered an image with some text on my page with this code:

```
.profilepic {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.contact {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 550px;
}
```

But now the image and text overlay the nav bar menu, whose position is fixed btw. Does anyone know how to sort this out? Or how to center the text and image without the

```
position:absolute;
```

code?

Comment: You can use z-index to specify a layer order - giving your nav a higher z-index should ensure it appears over your image. If you want more specific help though you'll need to post your HTML (or preferably a working example using JSFiddle or similar).

Comment: Could make a few suggestions but don't know what you may have already tried. It would also be helpful to get an idea of how your DOM is structured. Can you include some `html` as well? Just a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - enough for us to work with. You can combine your `css` and `html` in the Code Snippet purposely built for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) The z-index worked great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)